# Mule - WMQ - Outbound properties are lost in transition when message published to MQ

Tags: properties, mule, ibm-mq

I have created flow with WMQ/JMS Outbound connector to publish to Websphere MQ - Queue/Topic.

Flow #2, got Inbound Endpoint connector (WMQ/JMS Connector) to listen to these Topic/Queue.

I am expecting Flow #1 OutboundProperties to come in Flow #2 InboundProperties. But, they are not coming.

I tried this using:

WMQ Connectors

JMS Connectors

Both failed.
Any idea how to accomplish it ?

Comment: Post your config here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have managed to made it work... will post the config (working version) later.

Comment: You should post a self-answer with your working config.